# Is there a roadmap for Joomla development?

Tags: development

I recognize that most (all?) of the code is written by volunteers so it is hard for anyone to say that 'this' is the order that things need to be done and 'this' is what we have to do next.

That being accepted, I assume that there is a road map that the core contributors have discussed and is generally accepted as the plan for Joomla development and goals. Is there a place to read through this? Can suggestions be made? If I contribute code not in the plan is it likely to get accepted?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The developers have a roadmap at this link : http://developer.joomla.org/cms/roadmap.html which essentially states that the main focus right now is to unify and streamline the development process for the good of the project.  That is, they will wrap the Framework back into the CMS development so that it can have the same Bug Squad.

The roadmap further addresses UX/UI issues and legacy handling.

The future of the project at this time is to become more ubiquitous among developers, by making the library and framework more accessible.  Distribution will become widespread and reach untapped markets, if all goes well with their plans.

Comment: The roadmap is clearly outdated, when to expect an update?

Comment: PLT has a roadmap internally, but it needs a bit refinement first before it can be published. Part of it is published in the 3.4 announcement (http://developer.joomla.org/news/583-announcing-joomla-cms-3-4.html).

Comment: An updated Joomla 3.4 timeline can be found at http://developer.joomla.org/news/601-joomla-3-4-release-timeline-update.html

Answer (score 5):

As of ***25 April 2014*** the PLT has published a new sort of a "roadmap" or a Development Strategy for Joomla! basically announcing a new release cycle.

[Joomla! Development Strategy](http://developer.joomla.org/news/586-joomla-development-strategy.html) - here is the whole development strategy explained, rather long and boring.

[Joomla! Improved Release Cycle: For the People by the People](http://developer.joomla.org/news/584-joomla-improved-release-cycle-for-the-people-by-the-people.html) - very short (and rather vague) version of the Development Strategy.

[FAQ's for Joomla's Improved Release Cycle](http://developer.joomla.org/news/587-faq-s-for-joomla-s-improved-release-cycle.html) - should answer most of the questions you might have.

[Announcing Joomla! CMS 3.4](http://developer.joomla.org/news/583-announcing-joomla-cms-3-4.html) - announcement of the 3.4 release of the Joomla! CMS, which is planned to be released on July 15, 2014.

Comment: I'd add http://developer.joomla.org/news/583-announcing-joomla-cms-3-4.html. It contains the "roadmap" for 3.4.

Comment: Added, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Look here please: http://developer.joomla.org/cms/roadmap.html

Summary:

1. Reconcile Joomla! Platform code.
2. Roll back MVC Legacy Classes
3. Embrace Rapid Application Development
4. Merge legacy library and Joomla! library folders
5. Increase Joomla! library unit test coverage
6. Create distributions for CMS packages
7. Unified Content Model
8. Unified Page Model
9. Unified Site Administration
10. New Feature Implementation
11. UX and Accessibility
12. Internationalisation